# Can't center text in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, responsive-emails

This is a silly problem, but have tried everything I can think of and still can't figure out how to center these two cells of text in Outlook 2003.

[image]

Here's a link to the full html file: https://github.com/justintemps/flash-updates/blob/master/dest/index-prod.html?ts=4

The offending (part that won't center) is below.

```
<table class="body" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin: 0 auto 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="text-align: center;">
                <center>
                    <table class="bodyContainer" align="center" width="600" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 600px; padding-top: 5px; table-layout: fixed; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td class="mainImageContainer" align="center" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
                                    <!-- INSERT LINK HERE -->
                                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                                        <!-- INSERT IMAGE URL HERE -->
                                        <img class="mainImage" width="600" alt="" src="http://www.ilo.org/wcmsp5/groups/public/---dgreports/---dcomm/documents/image/wcms_484941.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 600px; padding-top: 5px; table-layout: fixed; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr align="center">
                                <td class="mainTitleContainer" align="center" width="600" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
                                    <!-- INSERT LINK HERE -->
                                    <a class="noDecorate" href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                        <h2 class="mainTitle" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #2f2f2f; margin: 0; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: left;">The International Labour Conference 2016 starts</h2>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr align="center">
                                <!-- INSERT SUMMARY HERE -->
                                <td class="bodyText" align="center" width="600" style="font-family: georgia, Palatino, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; text-align: left;">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                    <span>
                                        <!-- INSERT LINK HERE -->
                                        <a class="decorate" href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #37468E; font-weight: bold;">Read More&#187;</a>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few **`text-align:left;`**'s in there that are overriding the centering you're doing in parent tags.

```
...padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: left;">The International...
```

and

```
...line-height: 20px; text-align: left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
```

If you remove the **`text-align:left;`** from the examples above, these areas should center justify.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

it's work.please copy in all HTML body tag like [here](https://codepen.io/siam786/pen/qNBJJz?editors=1000)

Comment: Thanks, Shohrab. I know it works in CodePen, but I still can't get it working in Outlook 2013.

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.